# Send Email to Users after Deleting Account

Tags: users, email, account

It is possible send email for deleting account on wordpress??

Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt6Ks.png

Ok after click send email to user with ex text: "your account has been deleted" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The full answer is here in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_user

<s>So I won't repost its code.</s>

```
function my_delete_user($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $email = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID = '" . $user_id . "' LIMIT 1");

     $headers = 'From: ' . get_bloginfo("name") . ' <' . get_bloginfo("admin_email") . '>' . "\r\n";
     wp_mail($email, 'You are being deleted, brah', 'Your account at ' . get_bloginfo("name") . ' is being deleted right now.', $headers);
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user');
```

Comment: +1 mostly for the content of the email

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Send Mail on User Delete](https://wordpress.org/plugins/send-mail-on-user-delete/) plugin. It gives you to change the mail content too from admin. You can send email both user as well as admin.

Comment: FYI plugin referenced above has not been updated in 4+years.